# If $\lim_{x\to\pm \infty}f(x,c)=0$ $\forall c\in [a,b]$ then $\lim_{||(x,y)||\to\infty}f(x,y)=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

If $f:\mathbb{R}\times [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function with $$\lim_{x\to\pm \infty}f(x,c)=0$$ for all $c\in[a,b]$, does that imply that $$\lim_{||(x,y)||\to\infty}f(x,y)=0$$ (when taking values $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times [a,b]$)?

This intuitively seems true to me, any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: My first instinct is 'no'; the function may go to 0 at different rates across different horizontals, therefore there can be a path going to infinity where the function is bounded away from 0

Comment: That is true when considering open intervals, but I don't know if the same can be done with compact intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a counterexample following the idea in my comment: let's say $[a,b] = [0,1]$ for simplicity's sake. Then,

For any $x > 0$, define $f$ along the short vertical $y \in [0,1]$ as a piecewise linear path,

$$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    ye^x & 0 \leq y < e^{-x} \\
    2 - ye^x & e^{-x} \leq y < 2e^{-x}\\
    0 & 2e^{-x} \leq y \leq 1
\end{array}\right.$$

This draws a line from a height of $0$ to a height of $1$ and back down to $0$, completing a small triangle with a peak at $e^{-x}$. As $x \to \infty$, the triangle thins and its peak moves towards $0$.

Therefore, across any fixed horizontal $y = c$, the triangle will eventually thin and squeeze under this threshold, at which point the function becomes constantly $0$.

However, it is clear that the function does not shrink uniformly to $0$; along the path $y = e^{-x}$ the function rides the peak of this triangle and is therefore constantly $1$.

Comment: You can mirror this definition and obtain a function with similar behavior for $x < 0$ if you define in terms of $|x|$

Comment: Thank you so much